# print alignment dont get correctly using javascript and css

Tags: javascript, php, css

[image]I want to print content in a div using javascript and css.My main div is with id 'preview'.Content in a div taken from database using php and mysql.But in print page data get vertically,not in correct position

My page image and print image are

page image

print image[image]

My code is given below

```
      <?php
  error_reporting(0);
  $host='localhost'; // Host Name.
  $db_user= 'root'; //User Name
  $db_password= '';
  $db= 'excel'; // Dat
  $conn=@mysql_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password) or die (mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db($db) or die (mysql_error());
  $sql = "select * from first order by id";
  $rsd = @mysql_query($sql);
  ?>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  function printDiv(divID)
   {
        var divElements = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;
        var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = 
          "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" + 
          divElements + "</body>";
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;
     }
  </script>
 <style type="text/css" media="print">
 @media print{ #preview{ height:100%;overflow:visible;} } 
 </style>
 <style>
   #my-list{
   padding: 10px;
   padding-left:15px;
   width:auto;
   margin:auto;
   }
  #my-list > li {
   display: inline-block;
   zoom:1;
   *display:inline;
   }
  #my-list > li > a{
  color: #666666;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 3px 8px;
   }
  </style>

 <input type="button" value="Print" onClick="javascript:printDiv('preview')" />
 <div id="preview" style="width:1000px; margin:auto;">
 <ul id="my-list" >

    <?php  



    $si=1;

    while($fet=mysql_fetch_array($rsd))
    {
        ?>
             <li> 



           <div class="droppable2"  style="border-color:#3300FF; 
            border:solid #999999;  height:180px;width:180px;position:relative; " >
            <div style="float:left;position:absolute; bottom:30px;" class="left">


            </div>
            <div style="float:right;">
            <p style="color: #003399;  font-size: 10px;
              padding-right:5px; font-weight:800; ">www.selafone.net</p>
             <table style="font-size:10px;" >
             <tr> <td >USERNAME: </td> <td> <?php echo $fet['name']; ?> </td></tr>
              <tr> <td>PASSWORD:</td> <td> <?php echo $fet['email']; ?></td></tr></table>
            </div>
             <div  style="position:absolute;background-color:#FF0000;
              padding-bottom:0px; bottom: 0;  
              width: <?php echo $width;  ?>px; height:36px;  "><div style="color:#FFFFFF; padding-left:30px;
              vertical-align:middle;font-weight:100;padding-top:10px; 
              font-size: 8px;"><strong> International prepaid Calling Card</strong></div></div>
              </div>


      </li>
        <?php   
    $si=$si+1;  
    }

    ?>

    </ul>

    </div>
```

Any body give any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't replicate the exact problem you are facing, but I believe I traced the problem to your print 'innerHTML' replacement creating a document that doesn't have a 'doctype' which then conflicts with the descendant targeting you are doing on the list item.

The list item in the CSS is using 'display:inline-block' which is not being applied in the print view.

Try the CSS changes below:

```
#my-list li {
 display: inline-block;
 zoom:1;
 *display:inline;
}
#my-list li > a{
 color: #666666;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 3px 8px;
}
```

Hope this helps.